# Set variables from closure

Tags: swift, closures, nsurlsession

I need the value of my responseString as it contains data I'll send to the next ViewController, I've read up on completionHandlers and I also found somewhere that my responseString data can only live inside the variable, is there any workarounds because I never expected this would ever be a major problem.

```
    func GenerateData
    var responseString = "baddata"

    let request = NSURL(string: postString)

    // NSLog("We are getting" + "this :" + postString )
    //request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL((request)!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?,
        error: NSError?) -> Void in
        //do something
        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

         responseString = NSString(data: data! , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
         print("responseString = \(responseString)")
     })
    task.resume()


    return responseString

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Session like this.

Add this your controller top side

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Find

```
print("responseString = \(responseString)")
```

Add thats later

```
prefs.setObject(responseString, forKey: "responseString")
prefs.synchronize()
```

And now your responseString ready to read.
Open another controller view controller and do this.

And use like this

```
    let yourString:NSString = "\( prefs.valueForKey("responseString") as! String!)"
  self.responseText.text = yourString as String
```

Comment: Apparently, it's an asynchronous function and saving the responseString as prefs only helped when I reloaded the app